# ¿Como aplicar Pipelines para que las variables categóricas las convierta en ficticias y también escalar las variables?

Tags: python, machine-learning

Estoy intentando automatizar las tareas de convertir variables categóricas en variables ficticias y escalar las variables mediante Pipelines de ML.
Anexo el procedimiento que hasta ahora he hecho.
Aquí está la primera canalización para transformar la variable categórica en una variable codificada en un solo uso

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# Pipeline for transforming categorical variables
catTransformer = Pipeline(steps=[('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])
```

normalicé las variables numéricas y seleccioné las características numéricas según los tipos de datos float64y int64, lo mismo con las variables categoricas

```
# Selecting numerical features
numFeatures = X.select_dtypes(include=['int64','float64']).columns
numFeatures

# Selecting Categorical features
catFeatures = X.select_dtypes (include = ['category']).columns
catFeatures
```

Hice un motor de transformación utilizando la ColumnTransformer()función

```
# Creating the preprocessing engine
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('numeric', numTransformer, numFeatures),('categoric', catTransformer, catFeatures)])
```

Apliqué el motor llamado preprocessor para transformar los datos de entrenamiento

```
# Transforming the Training data
Xtran_train = pd.DataFrame(preprocessor.fit_transform(X_train))
print(Xtran_train.shape)
Xtran_train.head()
```

El problema es que la salida me debería arrojar un DataFrame con las variables numéricas y categóricas separadas, en cambio me regresa un DataFrame con una sola columna sin formato, Alguien podría decirme que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido@. Las publicaciones que contienen el código en imagenes, no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Por favor, revisa [como hacer un pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edita tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte. Gracias

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: por favor pon el código como texto y coloca la etiqueta de python

Comment: Bienvenida Nancy, todos aquí estamos tratando ayudarte, pero para ello necesitamos la información completa, o al menos un código que reproduzca tu error. Hay muchas variables que aparecen en tu código y no se saben de donde vienen, por lo que no podemos reproducir tu error, algunas de estas variables son `X`, `numTransformer`, `X_train`.